# iPhone framework for presenting lists and details about sales items

Tags: iphone, web-services

Instead of starting from scratch, I was wondering if there were any ready made iPhone functionality for presenting a store's item lists (small picture and main info) and detail pages (all images and full info).

All data is already stored in an online database and setting up Web Services or the like for communication is not a problem, but iPhone development experience is limited.

Do you know of anything of that nature that I might utilize?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect opportunity to develop a web application specifically for the iPhone.  I can't remember the name of the book off the top of my head, but do know that it's offered by O'Reilly.  The other upside is you will now have an app that's accessible by other devices also.

[Here's](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596805791) the book, it even includes the hooks to interface natively to the iPhone.

Comment: Already did that and in my opinion it is the way to go, however the client wants the "prestige" of an actual iPhone application. So no two ways about it, go figure.

Comment: Funny, second time I've heard that sentiment in 2 days - but I get it :)

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is looking through some of the code examples available at Apple's iOS developer [site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).  I believe there is a 'Recipe List' example that might be similar to what you are looking to do.  Hope that helps!